# Can calloc ever safely be used without free?

Tags: c

I'm a Java programmer with almost no C/C++ experience trying to adapt some simple C/C++ code used with the JNI.

I read that an array (or any other memory chunk) allocated with single calloc() should always be deallocated with single free() call with SAME pointer as returned by malloc. It causes a memory leak if it's not free'd.

The C/C++ code I'm adapting uses calloc(), but has no corresponding free() call. Are there any situations where it shouldn't have a free() call, or is the code badly written?

Comment: Sounds broken/lazy to me.

Comment: After you've allocated memory, you must free it. No exceptions. Or get a memory leak otherwise.

Comment: Using `free()` is always a good idea to increase **heap re-usability**. Otherwise for large software the **heap** or the **free store(in C++ lexicon)** may get exhausted and the rest will be disaster.

Comment: In C++ you should be using `new`/`delete`. Better still is to use smart pointers

Comment: An array declared like `int arr[42];` will be automatically freed when it goes out of scope, unless you declare it as `static`. When you dynamical allocate memory with `malloc()` or `calloc()` you always have to release that memory with `free()` or a leak will occour. In C++ the right keyword are [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and `delete`, but you should instead use the Standard Library containers like std::vector or take advantage of [RAII](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#finally).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `calloc(...)` or `malloc(...)` should always be accompanied by a corresponding `free()` so that the application/OS can reclaim the memory for other purposes. An application that doesn't free up memory will "leak" that memory and make it unusable.

If you do not use `free()`, a sensible operating system will make that memory available again when the application closes, but a program that relies on the OS to clean up any memory leaks is badly programmed and should be fixed.

This (as you already know) is unlike Java, which has a garbage collector to periodically clean up any memory that is not used anymore.

As a general additional note, it is not required to use the *same pointer* to free memory. For example, you could do this:

```
// Create an array of 10 integers.
int *x;
x = calloc(10, sizeof(int));

// Create another pointer 'y', which uses the same array as x.
int *y;
y = x;

// Delete the array. Both 'x' and 'y' are unusable now.
free(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Allocations should always be paired with deallocations in library code and code that gets run in loops.

Basically you don't want unfreed unreferenced memory to accumulate and thereby increase the memory consumption of your process.

Skipping deallocations when you simply want to exit is permissible (though generally frowned upon), and it can speed up your exit a little bit if you have lots and lots of deallocations to do.

In C++, allocations and deallocations may be paired implicitly, via destructors (RAII):

```
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Free{
    void operator() (void* x){ 
        free(x); 
    }
};

int main(){
    char *p = new char; 
    delete p; //an explicit deallocation

    std::unique_ptr<char, Free>  ptr { (char*)calloc(1,100) };
    return 0;
    //an implicit deallocation
    //-- you don't see the free but unique_ptr's destructor does call it here
}
```

In fact, relying on destructors is the absolutely preferred way of handling dynamic memory in C++.

You can use tools such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check that in a program run, your allocations and deallocations are paired (the  g++ standard library usually makes one unpaired allocation when you first directly or indirectly call new, but the rest of your allocations should be matched with `free`s)

If I run the above program via:

```
valgrind ./a.out
```

I get:

```
==25629== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25629== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25629== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25629== Command: ./a.out
==25629== 
==25629== 
==25629== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25629==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==25629==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 72,805 bytes allocated
==25629== 
==25629== LEAK SUMMARY:
==25629==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25629==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25629==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25629==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==25629==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25629== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==25629== 
==25629== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25629== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

which means that all is well, because only the allocation made by the standard library (the one for 72,704 bytes) remained unpaired with a deallocation.

Answer (score 1):

Operating systems these days free memory allocated by programs when they exit. But this is a bad practice to rely on the operating system to free the memory for you. So obviously its badly written.

Answer (score 1):

OS frees all process resources on process exit, but it is not a good idea to count on it if your program has a main loop and frequenty allocates memory ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you use malloc(), and similar, you must make a call to free(), without any exception. But what you should know is that dynamic memory should never be used as it introduces too much indeterminateness to the behaviour of your program and often too much bugs related to memory leaks. As stated in MISRA/C standard as well as other safety critical embedded standards (which should be applied to non-critical mainstream x86 software too) malloc is strictly forbidden.To reach a high level of reliability in your software you must forget the existence of dynamic memory and start using only static memory. Just pre-allocate a big static array and all worries are gone.