# Should you free memory passed to prctl()?

Tags: c, linux

I am using `prctl()` to change a pthreads thread name in C:

```
  // Set our thread name to assist with debugging a running process
  char *threadName = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
  sprintf(threadName, "My Own Thread");
  prctl(PR_SET_NAME, threadName);
```

My question is whether or not I should free the `char *threadName` immediately after the `prctl()` call?

Does `prcrl()` take a safe copy of the string param, allowing me to free the provided variable whenever I like?

Memory testing with valgrind highlights no issues when I do the free. My concern is causing hard-to-trace concurrency/memory issues.

EDIT: I do not believe the suggested question [Can calloc ever safely be used without free?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38941962/9957820) answers the specific point here about *system/kernel functions* and specifically `prctl()` requiring the caller to not free the provided memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can calloc ever safely be used without free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941962/can-calloc-ever-safely-be-used-without-free)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - interesting read but I do not feel it answers whether kernel functions like the one mentioned require a free() or not?

Comment: Oh, ok. I think I missed the main point of your Q. Looks like you want to know if your string is duplicated by the kernel and if you can destroy it safely after your `prctl` call. Is that correct? If yes, the kernel copies it (by means of `copy_from_user`). It's not safe for the kernel to manipulate user-land data directly.

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly what I was after, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not find any documentation explicitly stating that it's safe to free a string passed to `prctl( PR_SET_NAME, name )` (it may very well exist somewhere).

An examination of the man page, the glibc source, and the Linux kernel source indicate that it's safe to free the memory after `prctl()` is called.

The [Linux `prctl()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) states this for `PR_SET_NAME`:

> **PR_SET_NAME (since Linux 2.6.9)**
>
> Set the name of the calling thread, using the value in the
>                 location pointed to by `(char *) arg2`.  The name can be up to
>                 16 bytes long, including the terminating null byte.  (If the
>                 length of the string, including the terminating null byte,
>                 exceeds 16 bytes, the string is silently truncated.)  This is
>                 the same attribute that can be set via `pthread_setname_np(3)`
>                 and retrieved using `pthread_getname_np(3)`.  The attribute is
>                 likewise accessible via `/proc/self/task/[tid]/comm`, where `tid`
>                 is the name of the calling thread.

Key here is the statement "The attribute is likewise accessible via `/proc/self/task/[tid]/comm`".  That means the supplied string has to be copied into kernel space.  The wording "using the value in the location pointed to by `( char * ) arg2`" certainly does seem confusing and unclear, leaving open to possibility that the very string passed to `prctl()` is used directly.  But to be "accessible via `/proc/...` requires a copy be made in kernel space.

The [glibc source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/search?p=1&q=prctl&unscoped_q=prctl) is a bit hard to follow.  I couldn't definitively find the actual code that's executed when your process calls `prctl()`, but what I did find were system calls that directly pass the pointer to the kernel.

The [Linux kernel source is pretty clear](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9221dced3069cc9ae2986ba1191b02dae560df28/kernel/sys.c#L2331). as the string is copied from user space to kernel space:

```
case PR_SET_NAME:
    comm[sizeof(me->comm) - 1] = 0;
    if (strncpy_from_user(comm, (char __user *)arg2,
                  sizeof(me->comm) - 1) < 0)
        return -EFAULT;
    set_task_comm(me, comm);
    proc_comm_connector(me);
    break;
```

A definitive test would be to call `prctl()` to set the name, then modify the string that was passed to `prctl()`.  If the name of the thread doesn't change, then a copy must have been made.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in general, standard functions will copy buffers if needed before returning, leaving ownership of the original passed buffer to the calling function.